# React Navigation - tutorial for nesting navigators: TabNavigator overwrites StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

While working through the React Navigation [tutorial](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting) on nesting navigators, I find that the tab navigator, `MainScreenNavigator`, overwrites the stack navigator, `SimpleApp`. The result is that the tabbed screens called in that object are the only ones that are displayed. The expected behavior that does not occur is that the button which links to the nested navigator never displays, so I cannot access the `ChatScreen` object.

```
const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
  Recent: { screen: RecentChatsScreen },
  All: { screen: AllContactsScreen },
});
```

I've spent hours trying to understand what I might have missed. This is my first attempt at learning this package, so I don't know if the tutorial is wrong, or that I missed a detail that breaks the process. The entire `App.js` file is located [here](https://gist.github.com/mjstelly/2f2a2ee1389cb831592bf30dd7dca4ad).

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to pass StackNavigator's navigation to screens of Tabs. Because they are only screens you can deal with now since it's a initial screen.

```
const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
  Recent: { screen: ({screenProps}) => <RecentChatsScreen screenProps={screenProps}/>,
  All: { screen: ({screenProps}) => <AllContactsScreen screenProps={screenProps}/> },
});

//I added the export keyword.
export const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { 
    screen: ({navigation}) => <MainScreenNavigator screenProps={{myStackNavigation:navigation}}/>,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'My Chats',
    },
  },
  Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
})
```

Now, you can call below code in RecentChatsScreen or AllContactsScreen.

`this.props.navigation.screenProps.myStackNavigation.navigate('Chat');`

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll test it today. One thing to note, this is not my code. It is straight from the tutorial. It'll have to be fixed to avoid others having the same problem as I had. I may have time to update it. Don't know yet.

Comment: OK. let me know if you have a problem. @MikeS.